# How to change the default font size of XTerm?

Tags: command-line, xterm, fonts

XTerm font is very small. How can I set it larger?

Comment: this also would be helpful - avoid bold chars on it http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31999/how-to-make-xterm-never-use-bold-characters

Comment: This is exhaustive, and gives a bit of insight to the xterm program:  http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html

Answer (score 131, accepted):

If you don't already have one, create a file in your home directory named `.Xresources` to store your preferences for various X programs. Append a line to the file such as

```
xterm*font:     *-fixed-*-*-*-18-*
```

This informs `xterm` to use the 'fixed' font at size 18. From here, to incorporate the changes you've made you can either:

- restart X; or
- run `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources` in a terminal

All new `xterm`s should now have the font change.

If you run `man xterm` and go down to the RESOURCES section, you can find a wealth of additional, configurable `xterm` options.

Comment: Thanks noffle it worked....but how can i set the dimensions of the xterm windows to a fixed ones?

Comment: The X resource for dimensions is `geometry`. So something like the following in your `.Xresources` would work: `xterm*geometry: 110x50`.

Comment: You're welcome. Consider creating a separate question in the future for the geometry issue rather than tacking it into a comment: it makes it harder for others to find.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning 'xrdb -merge' part, that did the trick!

Comment: Have this same question, both font-size and resize issue, thanks @noffle

Comment: `xterm: cannot load font '*-fixed-*-*-*-38-*'` `Warning: Shell widget "xterm" has an invalid geometry specification: "*-fixed-*-*-*-38-*"`

Answer (score 90):

Use -fa and -fs parameters:

```
xterm -fa 'Monospace' -fs 14
```

Comment: This does not "change the default font size" (as requested)!

Comment: That works at the command line but not from the GUI.

Comment: Using `Monospace` will not just change the size but use a quite different font (at least that's the case on Ubuntu 18.04). And I find `Monospace` to be using excessive amounts of anti-aliasing which makes it looks blurry when viewed next to an `xterm` window using the default font.

Comment: To list monospaced `xterm` fonts: `fc-list | cut -f2 -d: | sort -u | grep -i Mono`. If you prefer sans fonts, try `DejaVu Sans Mono`, `Liberation Mono`, `Noto Mono` or `Ubuntu Mono`.

Comment: +1 Excellent. Only command line one that worked for me.

Answer (score 67):

You can add the following as an example to your `~/.Xresources` file:

```
! Use a truetype font and size.
xterm*faceName: Monospace
xterm*faceSize: 14
```

Then run the following:

```bsh
xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
```

Comment: Indeed the best answer, since is enable TrueType fonts. I came to the same after reading this page: [XTerm introduction and TrueType fonts configuration](http://www.futurile.net/2016/06/14/xterm-setup-and-truetype-font-configuration/)

Comment: Only this worked on Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 50):

You can also Ctrl-Right mouse click for temporary change of font size

Comment: How do you find out what font size and face you have actually selected with this method, so you can make it the default in ~/.Xresources ?

Comment: @Geeb you can find out which font corresponds to which menu entry with `appres XTerm | grep -i utf8font`

Answer (score 14):

From messing with `/etc/X11/app-defaults/XTerm` file and man page for Xterm I found two methods.

**Method 1:** A simpler method but not permanent: hold Ctrl key and right click button. This should bring up a menu for VT fonts, which stays on only as long as you hold right click key. You should see 7 choices, the largest being huge, which is what I'm using because my vision isn't exactly good.

Source: xterm(1) man page, part VT Fonts, which states "The  fontMenu  pops  up  when when the “control” key and
       pointer button three are pressed in a window."

**Method 2:** Permanent. Look through `/etc/X11/app-defaults/XTerm`, find what sizes lines such as `*VT100.font1:` , choose one, and write somewhere `xterm*font:  10x20` (10x20 , again this is my choice for reasons I already stated).

About my system: I'm running Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: Didn't notice that dolzenko has already posted method 1 before. Oh, well.

Comment: And method 2, changing system files, is not recommended. You (and all users on your system) may loose your modifications any time when an update overwrites that file.

Answer (score 9):

One more option, add this to your `~/.Xresources` to make hotkeys for changing the font size:

```
XTerm.vt100.translations: #override \n\
  Ctrl <Key> minus: smaller-vt-font() \n\
  Ctrl <Key> plus: larger-vt-font()
```

If you use uxterm, be sure to use `UXTerm.vt100.translations` instead.

Then you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> to increase font size or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to decrease the size, just like you can with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+`right-click` and selecting one of the other font size options.

Answer (score 3):

you can also simply test them with :

> xterm  -fn "-*-clean-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*"

after sel with xfontsel

Answer (score 3):

Creating the .Xresources file with specified lines of code (provided in [the answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/161704/527764) by noffle) fixed my issue, but on reboot the settings got lost again.

If the settings specified in the .Xresource file are not getting reflected automatically, try adding the below line to `~/.bashrc`.

```
[[ -f ~/.Xresources ]] && xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
```

Comment: This should probably be a comment instead (on the answer you mention)