# How to customize xterm

Tags: 12.04, fonts, xterm

I would like to customize xterm because the default font-size is pretty small.
I would also like to change my **xterm** font to Inconsolata.

I have a few questions.

- How would i know my default xterm font-size and font-family(xrdb -query don't show my font information)?
- What is the path for my xterm font?
- What are the acceptable formats for xterm fonts?
- should i be only using Monospace?
- Where i should be storing configuration?
- Would it only affect xterm or other terminals like gnome-terminal?
- Any standard format for xterm configuration?

I've google a bit but just got me confused because i can't seem to find a standard syntax for some configuration. Others use the classname **xterm** or **XTerm** and with regards to fontsize:

I've found a lot of formats. Like:

```
XTerm*faceName: Monospace:size=20
```

or

```
xterm*font:     *-fixed-*-*-*-18-*
```

or

```
xterm -fa "fontname"
```

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04LTS.
I'm overwhelmed by the manpage of **xterm** since i'm just a beginner.
I would like to get help from you guys.

Comment: Do you know that you are running `xterm` and not the default `gnome-terminal`? You are correct, xterm configuration is an obnoxious, historically crufty mess; gnome-terminal has an Edit→Profiles menu which is far, far easier.

Comment: in ubuntu, i search xterm.

Comment: but others say that gnome-terminal is resource heavy.
and i'm using xterm for vim which show colors 256colorschemes better than gnome-terminal.

Comment: You should be using gvim if you want a vim in a window. You are making this more complicated for yourself than it needs to be. That's another form of "resource heavy".

Comment: If you want to see more than you ever wanted to know about the xterm program, check this out:  http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html

Comment: Here is a good Q&A that discusses this topic:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/161652/how-to-change-the-default-font-size-of-xterm

Answer (score 2):

you can use `xfontsel` to get the correct name of some fonts installed on your system. Then call it using for example `xterm -fa "-*-nimbus mono l-*"`

(you can also control+right click on the xterm window to get a menu)

But I advice you to use gnome-terminal or other alternative such as sakura or lxterminal which are easier to configure.

Comment: what do those asterisks mean?

Comment: I really like the ctrl-right-click method.  Quick and to the point, albeit temporary.