# Is there an option to make xterm's font size much larger than Huge?

Tags: fonts, xterm

I use exterm often and always `ctrl` + `right-click` to set the font size to `Huge`. However, I find that `Huge` is very small in high-res devices. It looks really tiny on my laptop's 10 inch fullhd monitor. I am wondering  if there is any easy way to increase the font size further than `Huge`. I searched the Internet (perhaps ineffectively) and found no solution for this.

Comment: Not tried it yet, but that looks close to what you want: http://askubuntu.com/questions/161652/how-to-change-the-default-font-size-of-xterm