# Finding and installing a good bitmap font for xterm

Tags: fonts, xterm

I love bitmap fonts in my `xterm`, they look very good, there is no subpixel rendering or other antialiasing, but the fact they are hand made in regards to every pixel makes it cool. But I do not know how to find such fonts on the Internet and how to install them in my Ubuntu and then select them with `xterm`.

What I need is a detailed instruction for all three steps:

- finding/downloading
- installing into x11
- make use by `xterm`

Here is how I set up `fixed-medium` now, but I have no much idea what it means, and how to select a particular file:

```
xterm -ls -font '-*-fixed-medium-*-*-*-18-*-*-*-*-*-*-9'  -b 20
```

This is what I used before, for TrueType fonts, which I do not want to use anymore for my `xterm`:

```
xterm -fs 11 -fa AndroidMono -geometry 120x30 -n 'terminal' -ls
```

Comment: I'm happy with `xterm -fa default -fs 12`  # :-)

Comment: @sudodus yes, `-f1` loads the default "proportional font" for you, (i.e. vector font) I was using proportional fonts for years, now I am just in a different mood and want my bitmap fonts!

Comment: Proportional font does not mean it's vectorized, actually.

Comment: In a real xterm, selecting is ctrl-R click and select the one you want.  Setting those (6) selections up is done in /etc/X11/app-defaults/XTerm.

Comment: @ubfan1 good suggestion, but unfortunately it only allows to change size and switch between the default True-Type and default non True-Type (along with few more options) but not really allows to select the type face.

Answer (score 3):

You have 80+ standard packages with "xfont" in their name. Some of these are bundles for specific purposes like "web", "biz", etc. so hundreds of x fonts available to install.

Setting up default fonts in an xterm is well covered in [How to Change the Default font size of XTerm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161652/how-to-change-the-default-font-size-of-xterm?rq=1)

One additional method of selection not covered in the above link using an escape sequence to change the font in an xterm.
First, ensure that "Allow Font Ops" is checked in the ctrl-R mouse button menu (near the bottom).
The echo command:

```
echo -n -e "\033]50;8x16\007"
```

sets the font to 8x16.  Put the command into a script  you can run, passing the font as an argument:

```
#/bin/bash
# mychfnt script
MYFNT=${1-8x16}
echo -n -e "\033]50;$MYFNT\007"
```

e.g. put an executable file named chfnt with the above into your $HOME/bin directory, and whenever you want to change fonts, use

```
xlsfonts
```

to list the available fonts, and then select one and

```
chfnt "-sony-fixed-medium-r-normal--24-230-75-75-c-120-iso8859-1"
```