# Any way to change Xterm font and color when I don't have admin permissions?

Tags: fonts, xterm

I'm currently using an SSH client to interact with my server at work, and I've been wanting to change the default font and color scheme for a while now.

I learned that I needed to figure out how to do that for my specific terminal emulator, and that happens to be Xterm. The answers that I found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161652/how-to-change-the-default-font-size-of-xterm) say that after creating a `.Xresources` file to run the command:

```
xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
```

but when I run it I get the message:

```
The program 'xrdb' is currently not installed. To run 'xrdb' please ask your administrator to install the package 'x11-xserver-utils'
```

Unfortunately I don't have admin privileges. Is there any way to work around this? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "using an SSH client to interact with"? are you running an Xterm on the remote server and displaying it on your local system via X forwarding? or does the SSH client provide its own local terminal?

Comment: Perhaps my wording was ambiguous, but I wasn't sure how to explain it. It's the former.

Comment: Well if you're invoking `xterm` on the remote system, perhaps the simplest workaround is to do so with explicit `-fg` / `-bg` / `-fn` options?