# Increase font size of terminal in a no-GUI situation

Tags: fonts, vnc

I'm using a docker file that builds an environment for robotics. It works great. I've attached a screenshot. [image]

As you can see it has a terminal window and a few other tools but it doesn't seem to have a normal desktop manager, at least I dont recognize it. Which is fine with me. I won't be using it in that mode. But the few times I do use it the font in the terminal window is too small and for the life of me I can't figure out how to do it.

What am I running here? How would I do something like making the font larger? Thanks!

Comment: If you see multiple windows with "decoration" (title bar, buttons, borders), you definitely have a GUI. Linux _does_ have a complete non-GUI mode, and the answers there would be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Freetype fonts

You can not only use bitmap fonts but often there are also nicer 'freetype' fonts in `xterm`

```
xterm -fa default -fs 13
```

So if you put a shellscript with a content similar to the above command line in `PATH` before the executable file `/usr/bin/xterm`, for example in `/usr/local/bin`, we can hope that your tool will pick it up and provide a better font and size.

From `man xterm`:

```
   -fa pattern
           This option sets the pattern for fonts selected from the
           FreeType library if support for that library was compiled into
           xterm.  This corresponds to the faceName resource.  When a CJK
           double-width font is specified, you also need to turn on the
           cjkWidth resource.

   -fs size
           This option sets the pointsize for fonts selected from the
           FreeType library if support for that library was compiled into
           xterm.  This corresponds to the faceSize resource.
```

Otherwise you might be able to use the resources `faceName` and `faceSize`. (I have never done that. You can try according to the advice in the accepted answer to [this AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161652/how-to-change-the-default-font-size-of-xterm).)

### Edit: How to select font and size interactively

> So there's no way to change the font of xterm once it's running, you have
>   to do it when it is launched? I'm doing this in a docker image so it's a
>   little convoluted to create that script to intercept the xterm command
>   that is offered when I click on the "desktop".
>
> Is that customizable at all?

Yes, you can modify the font and size interactively:

- Put the cursor into the `xterm` window's main area.
- Press **<kbd>ctrl</kbd>** and **<kbd>right-click</kbd>** to get a pop-up window
- Move the cursor to select 'freetype' or if installed 'truetype'
- Move the cursor to select the size you want

You will see tick marks at the selected options.

[image]

Comment: So there's no way to change the font of xterm once it's running, you have to do it when it is launched? I'm doing this in a docker image so it's a little convoluted to create that script to intercept the xterm command that is offered when I click on the "desktop". Is that customizable at all?

Comment: @pitosalas, Yes, I edited the answer to describe how to select font and size interactively.

Answer (score 3):

I recognize the [xterm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xterm) icon on those windows. There's a menu that probably offers a few more [bitmap fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_font#Bitmap_fonts) in larger sizes, but it's not easily discoverable:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + right click in the terminal, holding down the mouse button to keep the menu open

You might also be interested in:

- [How to change the default font size of xterm?](https://askubuntu.com/q/161652/1859)