# How do I increase the font size in all Uxterm windows in Ubuntu 18.04 with LXDE?

Tags: fonts

How do I increase the font size in all Uxterm windows I open in Ubuntu 18.04 with LXDE?

I tried this:
`xterm -fn -misc-fixed-*-*-*-*-40-*-*-*-*-*-*-*`

Even though that increases the font size, it only happens on the new window that gets open. Moreover, the font does not look pretty after doing that.

I would like the font to be big enough to make it readable on any Uxterm window I might open any time.

Thanks

Comment: When a terminal is opened, the configuration is read & fonts etc. are taken note of. Changes made during the session will impact new terminals, but change like you are describing are not expected to influence the current session/process as re-reading config files on every command (in case a change was made) is inefficient.

Comment: Thanks but then, how can I get uxterm to have a bigger and prettier font size whenever I open it without having to type the command I mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found a solution on the following link:
[How to change the default font size of XTerm?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161652/how-to-change-the-default-font-size-of-xterm)

I had to edit the file

```
/home/username/.Xresources
```

and replace

```
UXTerm*faceSize: 10
```

with

```
UXTerm*faceSize: 25
```

and launch

```
xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
```

This solution worked great!

Answer (score 0):

I'd try a different terminal emulator. Something like lxterminal of xfce4-terminal. They have graphical settings for things like fonts and colors.

If you want to stick with *xterm, then you'll have to edit .Xresources.

Some resources to get you started on Xresources:

1. http://linuxdocs.org/HOWTOs/XWindow-User-HOWTO-8.html
2. https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/x-window-system/9780937175149/Chapter09.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and the links!